# Gradle transitive repositories and credentials

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, bintray

### The Situation

I have multiple Android plugins using JFrog Bintray. These are all located in a different **maven** Repository. All of there are private repositories and therefor need to be authenticated before resolving these dependencies. There is **project A** and **project B** which are being developed internally and also a **project C** which is developed by a third party, which needs to implement **Project B** as a dependency, which in turn has a dependency on **project A**. For **project A** there will be a **bintray user 1** which is granted authority to **project A**. There will also be a **bintray user 2** for the third party to authenticate them for **project B**.

In **project B** there is a dependency on **project A** like so:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {
        credentials {
            username = 'bintrayUser1'
            password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser1'
        }
        url  "https://url-to-projectA"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.project:A:1.0.0'
}
```

Now there is another **project C** which has a dependency on **Project B** like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectB"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.project:B:1.0.0'
}
```

### The problem

The problem that occurs is that **bintray user 2** is asked to tell **Project C** where **Project A** is and needs to authenticate for it. I am wondering if it is possible that **bintray user 2** does not need to tell **Project C** where **Project A** is located and instead copy it over from **Project B**.

The same goes for the authentication. Is there a way **bintray user 2** can copy over the authentication from **bintray user 1** for **Project A**?

### The nonpreferred solution

Now what I could do is have **project C** also tell the location for each dependency in **project B**, but this doesn't scale well. This would be that each private dependency that I would put into **project B**, **project C** would need to locate and need authentication to. It would look something like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectA"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectB"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectX"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectX"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://link-to-projectX"
            credentials {
                username = 'bintrayUser2'
                password = 'bintrayAPIKeyForUser2'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.project:B:1.0.0'
}
```

This would become hard to manage and something you might not want to give **bintray user 2** authority to.

So again, is there a way to copy over the dependency locations and authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the **"nonpreferred solution".**

When Gradle builds the **projectC** it donwloads from maven the dependency `compile 'com.project:B:1.0.0'`.

With the dependency ,it downloads also the pom file which contains the nested dependency `com.project:A:1.0.0`. Then it tries to download the dependency from the repositories you have added in the `projectC/build.gradle` (or top level).
In this moment gradle **doesn't use** the projectB/build.gradle, but only uses the pom file.

It means that gradle **can't know the credentials** to download the dependency wihtout addind them in the `projectC/build.gradle` file.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case? (I'm asking since it is a two year old question)